# Disable function in a slideshow plugin that centres the image everytime the browser is refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I am using a slideshow plugin that centres the images in the browser. I have removed part of the js script to to disable the function so that the images in the slideshow stay fixed and do not move as the browser size changes.

```
// Adjust image when browser is resized
$(window).resize(function(){
base.resizeNow();
});
```

However, the problem remains that when the browser is refreshed the image is centred again. I need it to remain at a fixed distance from the left of the browser at all times. How do I disable the part of the plugin script that centres the image every time the browser is refreshed?

Please view this page that I am working on to see my problem: http://georgewoolfe.com/new-website/yogurt-line.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation of supersized.js](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#horizontal_center)

> ### horizontal_center
>
> Centers image horizontally. When turned off, the images resize/display from the left of the page.

So, consider setting `horizontal_center` to `0` in your script, i.e. the following region in `yogurt-line.html`:

```
$.supersized({
  autoplay : 0,
  transition : 0,
  keyboard_nav : 1,
  performance : 1,
  vertical_center : 1,
  horizontal_center : 1, // <- Set this to 0
  fit_always : 1,
  ...
```

Then, you could adjust the distance from the left using CSS rules such as `left`, if needed.

Comment: Thanks. It is still centring the image though? I have tried adding left rules to the image and the li however it always centres?

Comment: @angela I downloaded the page, set `horizontal_center` to 0, and it stopped centering the images. Make sure you set it to 0 and the browser cache is cleared.
Also, here is the CSS rule to set the left distance:
`#supersized li.activeslide img{left: 200px !important}`
Change 200px to whatever you wish, just make sure you set the `horizontal_center` to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you set horizontal center to 0 (false) as recommended by @Yasa Akbulut,
you would want to adjust your css, first setting the position of the slideshow to not be absolute:

```
ul#supersized li {position:initial}
```

Then you can adjust the position in the page where you want the slideshow.

I made a JSFiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/y3rqq561/2/